# Nodejs redirect url encoding

Tags: node.js, redirect, encoding

I have a server that makes url redirection using nodejs. I use this to make the redirection :
`response.writeHead(302, {Location: url}); response.end();`

This works well with normal url like google.com but when I have other characters like cyrillic it bugs for example if I do a url = 'ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Путин,_Владимир_Владимирович' (with https:// infront) then the redirection bugs. Do I have to somehow reencode the string before passing it to the redirection? because when I make a console.log(url), it's displaying the correct url with the cyrilic letters.

After some more test i manage to see that the data encrypted is as follow using node-icu-charset-detector:
----[NOTICE] charset: ISO-8859-2
----[NOTICE] redirect: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Путин,_Владимир_Владимирович](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

And the link I'm getting on my browser is like '[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%1FCB8=,*%12;048%3C8@*%12;048%3C8@%3E28G](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%1FCB8=,_%12;048%3C8@_%12;048%3C8@%3E28G)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode the url since HTTP header values doesn't support utf-8 encoded value:

```
response.writeHead(302, {Location: encodeURI(url)});
```

Comment: Thank you it was this, tho now i'll have to be more careful with what i'm doing :/